# Throttle large list for Journey Audience

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, journeybuilder

I have a list of 40K guests. I have set up a journey, but I want to throttle the send rate so that only 300 people from the full list enter the journey every day.  Is there any logic in the Journey entrance to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new Data Extension into which you'll inject your three hundred new contacts each day.

Then create a Query Activity (with update not overwrite) to just inject the top three hundred records from your 40K "List" (Data Extension) that haven't already been inserted...

```
SELECT TOP 300
    l1.*
FROM
    my40KList l1 LEFT JOIN
    myEventEntryDE l2
        ON  L1.SubscriberKey = l2.SubscriberKey
WHERE
    l2.SubscriberKey IS NULL
ORDER BY
    l1.RegistrationDate ASC
```

Schedule this Query in an Automation to run each day and have your Journey Builder Interaction only evaluate newly added records.

Answer (score 0):

Throttling is fairly limited:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000214182&type=1

It has a minimum of 500 per hour within a sending window.
[image]

You might consider doing this at the Automation studio (I'll look into that - or wait for someone to add a comment <-- Looks like Andrew did).

Or you could segment your 40K into groups or random segments